# Failed: No element found using locator:

Tags: selenium, protractor

When was using xpath method it throws an error

> Terminal error:
>   ( i.e Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, input[contains(@id, 'usertext')]) )

`element(by.id("usertext")).sendKeys("help")` (when i tries this way it executes perfectly)

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
describe('test MAYO site', function () {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  //browser.debugger();
  //login cookies
  browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  //login page testing
  it('URL', function () {
    // get testing project login url
    var loginlink = "https://mayo-gbs-stage.orbita.cloud:8443/chatbot/"

   browser.get(loginlink);
    browser.sleep(6000);
  });
  it("input", function(){
    element(by.xpath("input[contains(@id, 'usertext')]")).sendKeys("help");
    browser.sleep(6000);
  });
});
```

I need to use xpath functions by that way can make proper automation without searching for attributes

Comment: using `xpath` is NOT recommended, that is what protractor team says and I have to agreed https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide

Comment: Use Css locators. To do a better Ui Automation using protractor.

Comment: What does `I need to use xpath functions by that way can make proper automation without searching for attributes` even mean? You realize that your XPath is searching for the ID, which is an attribute, right? Also, you are using `contains()` which is not needed per your comment that `by.id("usertext")` works fine. You should be using ID. Full stop. But if you insist on using XPath, you can at least simplify it to `//input[@id='usertext']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find element with below snippet!

Using contains :

```
element(by.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'usertext')]"))
```

Using equal operator :

```
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='usertext']")),
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This should work.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='usertext']").send_keys("help")
```

Comment: @DebanjanB, Yes I should have add more context why I did this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because your XPath is not properly formed. You have

```
input[contains(@id, 'usertext')]
```

but it should be

```
//input[contains(@id, 'usertext')]
```

Having said that, I don't understand why people insist on using XPaths when they aren't needed. You stated that `by.id("usertext")` works just fine... if that's the case, why are you using XPath? XPath is less performant, inconsistent support, and so on. You should always use ID when available, CSS selectors should be next (best support and performance), and then a last resort would be XPath only when you need to find an element by contained text or do DOM navigation.